# Spread function fails

Tags: r, tidyr

R newbie here, re-building Python pipeline in R.

`d` is a data.frame():

```
$ day        (chr) "2016-10-13", ...
$ city_name  (chr) "SF", ... 
$ type       (chr) "Green", ... 
$ count      (int) 10, ...
```

I'm doing a `spread()` on the data from [`tidyr package`](http://garrettgman.github.io/tidying/):

```
d %>% spread(type,count)
```

Works fine running locally (Mac) with:

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan)
tidyr_0.6.1
```

I run the identical command on a Linux box, on the same input `d`, but it returns an error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(.variables, lengths != 0) : i evaluates to a logical vector length 3 but there are 930 rows. Recycling of logical i is no longer allowed as it hides more bugs than is worth the rare convenience. Explicitly use rep(...,length=.N) if you really need to recycle.
```

On Linux, I'm running:

```
R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS)
tidyr_0.6.0
```

Any idea what this error means, and why it would be thrown?

Edit: fixed this after updating `tidyr` on Linux, *and* re-starting the R session.

Comment: Without seeing the data, it's almost impossible to help you. Run `dput(d)`, copy the output and add it to your question.

Comment: error is fixed. appears to be related to `tidyr` version. i had updated to `tidyr_0.6.0`, but did not re-start my R session. after re-starting the R session, the error went away. still would be interesting to know what happened, but - in any case - error is now fixed.

Comment: I would still recommend that you share your data for reproducibility, because it could still be helpful to someone else who does not have the option to upgrade to a new version of the package.

Comment: ya. it's a few thousands rows, so hard to put all here. type of each col and the first instance of each are shown in my example. i just double-checked, and there's no missing values, and count is all ints > 0.